# Prove that $\sqrt{2} \lim_{x \to \xi^+} \frac{U''(x)}{U'(x)} \sqrt{U(\xi)- U(x)} = \sqrt{-U''(\xi)} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is from an exercise of Arnold's book "Mathematical methods of Classical Mechanics", and in chapter 4 there's an exercise in which the following limit arises:
$$\lim_{x \to \xi^+} \frac{\sqrt{2(U(\xi) - U(x))}}{x-\xi}$$
with the condition that $U(x)$ is smooth and obtains a local maximum at $\xi$ (so $U'(\xi) = 0$ ). After two applications of L'Hospital's rule the limit becomes
$$\lim_{x \to \xi^+} \frac{\sqrt{2}U''(x)}{U'(x)} \sqrt{U(\xi)- U(x)}$$
which, by the answer that the book gives, should be equal to 
$$\sqrt{-U''(\xi)} $$
I've tried substituting polynomials like $-(x-1)^2 + 2$ in there and the result seems to hold, however I cannot prove that the limit is equal to the expression given above. I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor's formula at $\xi$ gives
$$
U(x)=U(\xi)+\underbrace{U'(\xi)}_{=0}(x-\xi)+U''(\xi)\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{2}+o(|x-\xi|^2).
$$
Rearanging
$$
\frac{2(U(\xi)-U(x))}{(x-\xi)^2}=-U''(\xi)+o(1)
$$
and taking the limit gives the result.